# Itext7 generate pdf with Exception "Pdf indirect object belongs to other PDF document. Copy object to current pdf document."

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

i want to generate a pdf with itext 7,but some wrong happens to us:

```
com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Pdf indirect object belongs to other PDF document. Copy object to current pdf document.
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:195) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:185) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:115) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:187) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:115) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:187) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:115) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter.writeToBody(PdfWriter.java:383) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter.flushObject(PdfWriter.java:289) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.flushObject(PdfDocument.java:1572) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject.flush(PdfObject.java:159) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject.flush(PdfObject.java:127) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObjectWrapper.flush(PdfObjectWrapper.java:94) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage.flush(PdfPage.java:495) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage.flush(PdfPage.java:454) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:785) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
at com.itextpdf.layout.Document.close(Document.java:120) ~[layout-7.0.2.jar:na]
at com.xcz.afbp.thirdparty.service.impl.GeneratePDFService.generatePDF(GeneratePDFService.java:160) ~[classes/:na]
```

my generate code :

```
public void generatePDF(CreditQueryData creditQueryData, Map<String, UserCreditContentView> contentViewMap, List<PackageCreditContentView> needRetrievedCreditContentList, File pdfFile, BigDecimal score) throws Exception {

    if (!pdfFile.exists()) {
        boolean x = pdfFile.createNewFile();
        if (!x) {
            LOG.error("生成文件出错" + pdfFile.getPath());
            return;
        }
    }

    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream(pdfFile)));
    Document document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.A4);
    document.setRenderer(new DocumentRenderer(document));

    pdf.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new WatermarkingEventHandler());

    try {
        //operate code just add tableA tableB tableC...

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.info();
    } finally {
        document.close(); //exception throws here
    }


}
```

my only style code in itext7:

```
 private PdfFont bfChinese = null;
```

will be init in service constructor invoked:

```
 public GeneratePDFService() {
    String PdfFontPath = EnvironmentUtils.getClasspathFilePath("font/MSYH.TTF");
    try {
        bfChinese =  PdfFontFactory.createFont(PdfFontPath, "Identity-H", true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

i have tried set my font to *static*,but not works.

this is the place throw exception:

```
private void write(PdfIndirectReference indirectReference) {
        if (document != null && !indirectReference.getDocument().equals(document)) {
            throw new PdfException(PdfException.PdfIndirectObjectBelongsToOtherPdfDocument);
        }
        if (indirectReference.getRefersTo() == null) {
            write(PdfNull.PDF_NULL);
        } else if (indirectReference.getGenNumber() == 0) {
            writeInteger(indirectReference.getObjNumber()).
                    writeBytes(endIndirectWithZeroGenNr);
        } else {
            writeInteger(indirectReference.getObjNumber()).
                    writeSpace().
                    writeInteger(indirectReference.getGenNumber()).
                    writeBytes(endIndirect);
        }
    }
```

it's means i have two different document ,but i do not know when i have create another document.
Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I have experienced the same problem myself (and it took me hours to discover what I was doing wrong). As it turns out, you can use a specific `PdfFont` instance for only one document. As soon as you use a `PdfFont` instance it is linked to that document, and you can no longer use it in another document.

For instance:

```
class ThisGoesWrong {

    protected PdfFont font;

    public ThisGoesWrong() {
        font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(...);
    }

    public void createPdf() {
        ...
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph("test").setFont(font);
        document.add(p);
        ...
    }
}
```

The class `ThisGoesWrong` creates a correct PDF the first time you call `createPdf()`, but it shows the exception you have when you call it a second time.

I discovered that this solves the problem:

```
class ThisWorksOK {

    public ThisWorksOK() {
    }

    public void createPdf() {
        ...
        PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(...);
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph("test").setFont(font);
        document.add(p);
        ...
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is a bug (it certainly feels like a bug), so I will create an internal ticket at iText Group.

Comment: *I don't know if this is a bug (it certainly feels like a bug)* - if the font can eventually be embedded as a subset of the glyphs from some font program used in a document, it does make sense to consider it linked to a document. Otherwise you'd have to collect data on the glyphs used per document. Of course one can argue that the class name `PdfFont` is wrong, that it should be `PdfDocumentFont`.

Comment: @Cheng.T There's a check mark to the left, right next to the zero-score for my answer. Please check that mark as my answer solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for saving my hours of debugging.

Comment: @bruno-lowagie, pretty funny to hear you discuss your own creation with detachment, as if referring to a son who's move out. Anyway I ran into this message today, 3 years later... does that mean it was decided that this is a feature, and not a bug? Regardless, thank you for the guidance. Would have taken me forever and a day to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! Seems to me that itext API is a bit confusion. Since font objects are bound to a specific document, it would be much better if this fact is explicitly reflected on their constructors / static generators. Making this connection implicit is source of confusion, and nasty runtime surprizes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing it. It fixed one of my long pending bugs.

Answer (score 5):

To improve preformance you should reuse FontProgram:

```
private FontProgram bfChinese = null;

public GeneratePDFService() {
    String PdfFontPath = EnvironmentUtils.getClasspathFilePath("font/MSYH.TTF");
    try {
        bfChinese =  FontProgramFactory.createFont(PdfFontPath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And then:

```
public void createPdf() {
    ...
    PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(bfChinese, "Identity-H", true);
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph("test").setFont(font);
    document.add(p);
    ...
}
```

Comment: yeah,make font private , i have solved this , thank you any way.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved the issue.

1. Created an DocumentUtil class
2. Add a static method

   ```
   public class DocumentUtils {    
       public static PdfFont setFont() throws Exception {
               return PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.TIMES_ROMAN);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use the font like:

   ```
   PDfFont font = DocumentUtil.setFont();
   ```