# error while convert html to pdf in itext7

Tags: java, itext, html2pdf, itext7

To convert my html to pdf i use itext7's API convertToDocument, passing parameters the template's ByteArrayInputStream, the PDFDocument and convertProperties.

relevant code snippet:

```
HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(new ByteArrayInputStream(templateWritten), pdfDocument, converterProps);
```

As docs says, if I set baseURI of convertProperties there is no problem, but if I set PDF fonts this error shows up when the are many concurrent calls:

"Pdf indirect object belongs to other PDF document. Copy object to current pdf document.”

creation of convert properties

```
private ConverterProperties addResourcesForInitiative(String templateKey, FontProvider fontProvider) {
//        CustomDefaultFontProvider cdfp = new CustomDefaultFontProvider();
        ConverterProperties converterprops = new ConverterProperties();
//        converterprops.setFontProvider(fontProvider);
        converterprops.setBaseUri(ConfigurationManager.getParamValue("resource.path") + templateKey + "/resources/");
        log.info("Properties for conversione are setted. Url of folder loaded " + converterprops.getBaseUri());
        return converterprops;
    }
```

the object is created each call before convertToDocument API

am I missing something?

thanks all for your help

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same problem. It is related to (but not a duplicate of) [Itext7 generate pdf with Exception "Pdf indirect object belongs to other PDF document. Copy object to current pdf document."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44652992)

What I didn't understand about iText 7 at first, is that you have a `FontProgram` and a `PdfFont`.

- `FontProgram` is a class that contains all the information that iText needs to use a font program. It can be reused in a process that creates many different PDF files.
- `PdfFont` is a class that uses `FontProgram` in the context of a single document. Each `PdfFont` object belongs to exactly one `PdfDocument`.

If you try to use a `PdfFont` object to create another document, you get the error *"Pdf indirect object belongs to other PDF document. Copy object to current pdf document."*

In other words: you can't just reuse `PdfFont` objects, only `FontProgram` objects. This can be a problem when reusing `ConverterProperties` (or a `FontProvider`). The trick is not to cache `PdfFont` objects in a `FontProvider`, but cache the `FontProgram` instead.

As this is very confusing, I have asked the iText 7 development team to fix this. When I look at the closed ticketing system, I can see that the documentation will be fixed, and that efforts will be done with respect to the `ConverterProperties`. This means that you'll see improvements in the next version.

In the meantime, I have fixed this for myself by changing the way I use a `FontProvider` and `ConverterProperties`. New instances of `PdfFont` have to be created for every new document, and I understand why: `PdfFont` keeps track of the characters that are used in a specific document, and uses that information to create a font subset. That subset is different for every document; hence every document needs a different `PdfFont` instance.

I will add a reference to this question in the tickets about this topic.

Comment: thank you for the response. Now I try to fix the problem following your advice.

Is there a release date for the fix or the new verion of itext7 html2pdf?

Comment: I don't know, but @rafhens knows.