# Error about indirect object with some PDF when splitting / merging

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

I need to split or merge some pdf and I have some rare pdf that create the following exception.

```
com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Pdf indirect object belongs to other PDF document. Copy object to current pdf document.at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:216)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:206)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:112)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter.writeToBody(PdfWriter.java:393)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter.flushObject(PdfWriter.java:301)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.flushObject(PdfDocument.java:1743)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject.flush(PdfObject.java:183)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject.flush(PdfObject.java:152)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObjectWrapper.flush(PdfObjectWrapper.java:94)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage.flush(PdfPage.java:505)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage.flush(PdfPage.java:462)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:847)
at testPDF.PDF.splitByPage(PDF.java:564)
at testPDF.Main.main(Main.java:153)
```

After a bit of searching, i found this post about a similar problem :

[Itext7 generate pdf with Exception "Pdf indirect object belongs to other PDF document. Copy object to current pdf document."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44652992/itext7-generate-pdf-with-exception-pdf-indirect-object-belongs-to-other-pdf-doc)

In my case, I only split and merge the pdf, I don't touch to the content of the pdf, so I don't know why this exception happens. (From what I understood, the exception come from a problem in the copying of some font).

My code is the following :

```
public static void splitByPage(File pdfToSplit, int nbPageByPDF){
    try {
        // Open the document in reading mode
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfToSplit));

        List<PdfDocument> splitDocuments = new PdfSplitter(pdfDoc) {
            int partNumber = 1;

            @Override
            protected PdfWriter getNextPdfWriter(PageRange documentPageRange) {
                try {
                    return new PdfWriter(pdfToSplit.getAbsolutePath()
                                                   .substring(0,
                                                              pdfToSplit.getAbsolutePath()
                                                                        .lastIndexOf(".")
                                                              ) 
                                            + "splitPage_part" 
                                            + String.valueOf(partNumber++) 
                                            + ".pdf");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException();
                }
            }
        }.splitByPageCount(nbPageByPDF);

        // Close all the part created
        for (PdfDocument doc : splitDocuments) {
            doc.close(); // exception throws at the first closing
        }

        // Close the initial pdf to split
        pdfDoc.close();

    }
```

This code is inspired from this example : https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs/clone-splitting-pdf-file

For the merging, the same error happens when i try to close the new pdf where I appended the pdf that cause the exceptions. (But i can do it the other way. I can append another pdf (without this problem) to the pdf with the problem).

I think that i need to find the way to copy the font directly from the initial pdf to each pdf i create, but i can't find the way to do it.

If needed, i can send you in private the pdf with which the error occur, only in private since this pdf is a bit confidential.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion.

Comment: Please share the PDF in question. If absolutely necessary, you can do so via mail. You'll find an e-mail address in [my profile here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729265/mkl?tab=profile).

Comment: The pdf is from the company (APSYS) and a bit sensitive, so the pdf has been sent to the e-mail address. As it is a 60Mo file, we sent you a link to download it.

Comment: The issue already appears to be fixed. I tested your code and your file with the recent 7.1.2 and could reproduce the issue. Then I repeated the test with the current 7.1.3-SNAPSHOT development state and the error did not occur anymore.

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know about that. Do you have any information about the release date of the 7.1.3 version ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know; but I think the release date is pretty near.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has already been fixed in the current 7.1.3-SNAPSHOT development version state. More exactly, it has been fixed in commit 251606e55768a47cb68eb8c58f2f5fe36324d85b dated 2018-04-23 13:46:25 in the course of resolving issue DEVSIX-1913 (Fix copying of inherited page entries).

The cause was that in `PdfPage.copyInheritedProperties(PdfPage, PdfDocument)` for some properties the values were added as-is to the target document.

This is ok for direct objects; as in most PDFs the values of those properties are direct objects, this had gone unnoticed for quite some time.

The page property in question is the **CropBox** which in your example document happens to be inherited from the root of the pages tree and to have an indirect value.

Thus, you may either

- wait for a 7.1.3 release, or
- use a 7.1.3-SNAPSHOT, or
- backport the fix to your iText version. In this case you merely have to replace

  ```
  copyPdfPage.put(PdfName.CropBox, cropBox);
  ```

  by

  ```
  copyPdfPage.put(PdfName.CropBox, cropBox.copyTo(pdfDocument));
  ```

  in `PdfPage.copyInheritedProperties(PdfPage, PdfDocument)`.